# Resources to learn about block pipelining?

Tags: consensus

Are there resources to learn about block pipelining in Cardano as mentioned in [this video](https://youtu.be/_JNK4eDZFMA?t=401)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pipelining introduction blog post at

https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2022/02/01/introducing-pipelining-cardanos-consensus-layer-scaling-solution/